# mysql for junit testing in spring

Tags: mysql, spring, junit, h2

Is there any way to use MySQL for JUnit testing with Spring?

I ask this because I have a lot of store procedures in MYSQL and I have noticed that H2 is not working with SPs.

**Edit:**

Right now my configuration for `src/main` looks like:

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext =  SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}


spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pw
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Spring works fine with this configuration. It reads the `application.properties`, sees the `spring.datasource.*` and knows that I have set a datasource.

Everything is fine here.

Now, in tests I use something like:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Application.class})
@Transactional
public class TxServiceTest {

}
```

This is not going to run the tests against MySQL database. It will run the tests with H2 database. I need to use MySQL for testing because I am using many stored procedures.

I have tried many other combinations but none of them works. What am I missing here?

**Possible fix:**

I somehow found a way to make it work. I let the main project unchanged and inside my test project I added a new class:

```
@Configuration
public class PersistenceContext {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource dataSource = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb?noAccessToProcedureBodies=true");
        dataSource.setUsername("xx");
        dataSource.setPassword("yy");
        return dataSource;
    }

}
```

I don't like this solution too much but it is working.

Comment: The problem is your test, you shouldn't be using `@ContextConfiguration` but `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` instead.

Comment: Should I point `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` to my main project?

Comment: Well I would suspect that your tests are already pointing to that, else what the heck are you testing. Just replace `@ContextConfiguration` with `@SpringApplicationConfiguration`.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like Integration Test. First, make sure that your database is always up-to-date in order to avoid restores and work in common errors. You can use liquibase or flyway to manage deltas. Also, make sure that after execution of the tests the state of the database has not been altered. I mean if you have a table without data at the beginning, after the execution of your test this table must not have data. You can use dbunit or spring-dbunit which is an extension of dbunit for spring to manage this.

In order to use a local mysql database you can use this plugin http://mysql.jcabi.com/

**EDIT 01**

Replace your h2 dataSource bean:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Isn't there any way to just set to testing to run with the `dataSource` pointing to MySQL database? I mean doing it the same way as we do in our application (not in test).

Comment: Sure, you can. My approach was based on a Continuous Integration process.

Comment: Can you, please, give me a some hints on how to do it? I don't need continuous integration at this point and the way it works in my Application doesn't work in the tests too.

Comment: Do you mean how to write this unit test? Check this link about testing in spring http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#testing

Comment: I wrote unit tests and it is working but with H2 database by default. I want to make it work with MySQL. I tried to remove the H2 from my gradle.build but it is still looking after it, even if I provide something similar for dataSource with the configuration used in my Apllication.

Comment: I need some ideas on how to configure my tests to run with MySQL. I cannot find any source for inspiration. Or maybe I don't know what to look for.

Comment: If you already have a dataSource bean for h2 yo should change to mysql. I will edit my answer with the bean. If you need something else please modify your question.

Comment: I updated the post with some code snippets. My issue may be clear this time. I have also tried to create the dataSource like you have shown me in the answer but once I use this, Spring won't see the services I have in the main project.

Comment: Are you using spring-boot, right? Then, create another application.properties for testing purpose and point to mysql database. Also you can use profiles http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: I already tried that. I copied all `spring.datasource.*` entries from my `application.properties` to my test `application.properties` and it didn't work. I don't know why.